# Cannot subscript value of type

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

so I have created a class called Artist and I want to create a key value dictionary of type [Artist: Int], but when i try

```
dictionary[Artist] = 1
```

I get Cannot subscript value of type Artist

Here is my Artist class and the Hashable function

```
class Artist: Hashable {
let name: String
let lastName: String
var hashValue: Int {
    return NSUUID().UUIDString.hashValue
}

init(name: String, lastName: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.lastName = lastName
}
```

}

```
func ==(lhs: Artist, rhs: Artist) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just haven't noticed that I was trying to add class Artist and not an artist object as a key for the dictionary